# I just can't get this java code to work

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, multidimensional-array

Ok, so I just started leaning java in college, and this code is bugging me. Basically, my professor asked us to write a code that would have a two-dementional array that would store the distance between six cities and it would look like this:

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll1Bn.png)

Then, we would have to collect info about the user's route in a simple array, ex. 1 5 4 3 2 1.

and, based on the numbers informed by the user, we would have to calculate de total distance he drove.

This is what I wrote:

```
package routes;

import java.util.*;


public class Routes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[][] km = {{0, 20, 32, 45, 85, 90}, {20, 0, 20, 40, 65, 70}, {32, 20, 0, 25, 48, 49}, 
                        {45, 40, 25, 0, 39, 52}, {85, 65, 48, 39, 0, 36}, {90, 70, 49, 52, 36, 0}};

        int[] routes = new int[6];
        String[] route_r = new String[6];
        String[] city = {"Belo Horizonte", "Contagem", "Betim", "Juatuba", "Pará de Minas", "Itaúna"};
        int km_distance = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                System.out.printf("%d\t", km[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Enter your route: \n\n1. Belo Horizonte\t2. Contagem\t3. Betim\n"
                    + "4. Juatuba\t5. Pará de Minas\t 6.Itaúna\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            rota[i] = input.nextInt(); 
        }

        System.out.println("\nRoute: \n");

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            System.out.printf("%d. %s\n", i+1, city[route[i]-1]);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            km_distance = km_distance + km[route[i]][route[i+1]];
        }

        System.out.printf("\nTotal KM: %d\n", km_distance);
    } 
}
```

But for some unknown reason, it doesn't work. I debugged it and I realized the last for structure is only looping four times and then it crashes. Please send help.

edit: the output error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at rotas.Rotas.main(Rotas.java:41)
C:\...\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 47ms)
```

Comment: Please post the output error

Comment: Also this can't be the actual code, this won't compile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the correct variable name is `rota` not `route`. Anyway at this line:

```
km_distance = km_distance + city[route[i]][route[i+1]];
```

you are accessing index `i+1` which will be 7 at the end of the loop. It must be giving you an index out of range exception.

Comment: `city` is a `String[]`, so `city[route[i]][route[i+1]]` cannot compile - you cannot access elements of `String` using `[]` in Java

Comment: I just realized my mistake and changed it, I used km[route[i]][route[i+1]] instead, still not working, though

Comment: You're still trying to access `route[i+1]` which gives you the exception. You'll have to write you code accordingly to keep your index in range.